# CSS - layout with full width table and menu

Tags: html, css

I want to create full width table.
Did that with width:100%;
But. I want also an container on the right edge of the screen with open/close functionality (done by float:right and width change).
I need to response with table width when container size changes.
Something like: http://i62.tinypic.com/2ur6uy9.jpg

How to stylize this properly without any javascript and others?
Tried floats, tried different positionings and i still have no idea how to do this.

OK. Code below. Ugly and probably buggy becouse of still developing...

```
    <div id="full-content">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"></nav>

    <div id="dashboard">
        <div><h5>Dashboard</h5></div>
        <div>
            <ul><li class="head">[...]</li><li>[...]</li><li>[...]</li></ul>
            <ul><li class="head">[...]</li><li>[...]</li></ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="app-content">
        <div class="row">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">[...]</ol>
            <div class="datagrid">
                <table class="datatable table table-condensed table-striped table-responsive table-hover">
                   <thead>[...]</thead>
                   <tbody>[...]</tbody>
                </table>

    </div></div></div></div></div>...
```

css:

```
#dashboard { background-color: rgb(102, 102, 102); position: relative; float: right; }
.datagrid { float: left; width: auto; }
.container { width: 100%; }
.table { clear: left; margin: 10px 0 5px; width: auto; }
```

I hope it is all needed styles (hate bootstrap).
Now it looks like: http://i62.tinypic.com/dloqa8.jpg
After fev hours of trying everything i need a fresh look on this :|

Comment: Can you please show us your code what you have tried till now.

Comment: I'll suggest you to add `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (The corresponding [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/arielnmz/tys6K/)):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="table"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#right {
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    background: blue;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#right:hover {
    width: 200px;
}

#table {
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:200px;
}
```

I've replaced your table and sidebar for `<div>` elements, which are equivalent since in the end, a table is a `block` element too.

As you can see, I didn't specify a width for *table*, so it'll take any remaining space. On the other hand, I've set an specific width for the *dynamic* element and made it change its size when on `hover`. The *dynamic* element will grow and the *table* will then occupy the remaining space, giving the effect that it grows or shrinks like if it was being pushed by the *dynamic* element.